# Dúvida Escopo De Variáveis Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, escopo-de-variáveis, scope

no código abaixo tento utilizar as váriaveis lastLatitude e lastLongitude fora do escopo local. Preciso delas em initial. Tentei muitas coisas, alguém pode me ajudar a entender?

```
<script>
        var lastLongitude = "";
        var lastLongitude = "";

        function initMap() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: "locations.json",
                success: function processJSON(data) {
                    last = $(data).last();
                    last.each(function(i, item) {
                        lastLatitude = item.latitude;
                        lastLongitude = item.longitude;
                    });
                }
            });
            var initial = {
                lat: -22.9721291, // PRECISO DELAS AQUI
                lng: -43.7081429  // PRECISO DELAS AQUI
            };

            var finish = {
                lat: -22.986,
                lng: -43.6931
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: initial,
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoom: 7
            });

            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                map: map
            });



            // Set destination, origin and travel mode.
            var request = {
                origin: initial,
                destination: finish,
                travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            };

            // Pass the directions request to the directions service.
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == 'OK') {
                    // Display the route on the map.
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: suas variaveis estao sendo setadas de forma assíncrona, por isso quando passa na atribuicao do `initial` elas ainda nao foram setadas pelo callback da chamada do `ajax` coloca um `console.log('mensagem')` antes de atribuir o initial e um dentro do success pra voce ver qual executa primeito, o success vai executar depois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce só deve executar o restante do codigo, após ter recebido a resposta assíncrona da sua chamada do ajax, ai voce pode pegar o item para dentro da function e pegar os valores diretamente.

Nao tive como testar, mas acredito que assim deva funcionar.

```js
<script>
var lastLongitude = "";
var lastLongitude = "";

function initMap() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: "locations.json",
        success: function processJSON(data) {
            last = $(data).last();
            last.each(function(i, item) {
              resumeTasks(item)
            });
        }
    });
    
    function resumeTasks(item) {
      var initial = {
          lat: item.latitude, // PRECISO DELAS AQUI
          lng: item.longitude  // PRECISO DELAS AQUI
      };

      var finish = {
          lat: -22.986,
          lng: -43.6931
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: initial,
          scrollwheel: false,
          zoom: 7
      });

      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          map: map
      });

      // Set destination, origin and travel mode.
      var request = {
          origin: initial,
          destination: finish,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      };

      // Pass the directions request to the directions service.
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
              // Display the route on the map.
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
      });
    
    }
    
}
</script>
```

Comment: Testei e está perfeito André.

Agora vou procurar entender melhor por sua explicação. Grato de mais!